# Python code for prime factor with product giving error

Tags: python, factors, prime-factoring

**First loop in check_prime() is returning none value.**
I wanted a product of prime factors which are divisible by the given numbers

```
 def check_prime(num):
    if num > 1:
        for l in range (2, num//2):
            if num% l ==0:
                return False
            else:
                return True 

nlist=[]
two = 2
mul = 0
pri = int (input())
for i in range (2,pri):
    if check_prime(i):
        for j in range (2,i+1):
                if check_prime(j):
                    if two*i==pri:
                            nlist.append(two)
                    mul = i*j
                    if mul==pri:

                        nlist.append(i)
                        nlist.append(j)



print (nlist)
```

Comment: when you run `check_print(0)` then `if 0 > 1` is false so it never go to `for` loop and it ends function with default `return None`

Comment: Yes this is a just a problem with your program logic. If you can't see the error yet I highly recommend checking out pdb and stepping through your program line by line.

Comment: if you run `check_prime(2)` then you get `range(2,1)` and it never loop so it skip `for` loop and ends function using default `return None`

Comment: inside `for` loop in `check_prime()` you use `return` in `if` and `else` so it ends loop on first number - `l=2` and it doesn't check other nubmers.